# Javascript ajax race condition

Tags: javascript, race-condition

I hit a problem when **I store the html below into a div via ajax**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="site.com/file.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//use file.js object, get an exception because it doesn't exist
```

I fixed it by hosting it locally (`/myjs/file.js`). However that feels like its a hack. How do I make sure I load it first then execute? It seems like jquery.ready isn't the solution because the dom was ready before I ajax the html in. How do I wait properly?

Comment: Shouldn't `site.com/file.js` be `http://site.com/file.js`?

Comment: Don't take it so literally.

Comment: @BruteCode: Dude, we're programmers and software engineers. We're *all about* the detail... :-)

Comment: Show the code that contains the AJAX load.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mention `jQuery.ready`, so I'm guessing you use jQuery. If so, instead of putting `<script>` tags in the content of the `div`, use [`jQuery.getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/), which will give you a callback when the script is loaded.

If for some reason you can't do that, you can poll, e.g. in your code that wants to use something from `file.js`:

```
function doSomethingWithFileJS() {
    if (typeof anObjectProvidedByFileJS === "undefined") {
        setTimeout(doSomethingWithFileJS, 50);
        return;
    }

    // Here, you know file.js has been loaded
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to ensure that by doing:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="site.com/file.js" onload="myFunc()"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunc() {
   //use file.js object here
}
</script>
```

Where the `onload` attribute specifies a function to be executed once the script is loaded.

Comment: Is the `onload` attribute on `script` tags reliable even on IE? Older IE doesn't trigger a `load` event that you can hook via code, so I tend to suspect `onload` doesn't work with them either (they do `onreadystatechange` instead).

Comment: Yes, this would be a problem in older IE versions.

Answer (score 1):

Not the best approach but you could do something like this:

```
function checkIfLoaded(){
   if(typeof somefunctioninfilejs == 'function'){
     // load other script here
   }
   else {
     // not loaded queue up a check
     setTimeout(checkIfLoaded, 300);
   }
}
```